# How to return Console.Write output as a string in unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following code that returns an output of "AAlAleAlex" with the following code:

```
string s = "Alex";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                char start = s[j];

                Console.Write("{0}", start);
            }
        }
```

However, I want to get the output of the Console.Write into a string and return it, but the only thing that I could come up with is this, but it only returns the first letter for some reason. How could I return a valid string?

**Unit:**

```
public string FunnyName(string firstName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstName.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; )
            {
                char start = firstName[j];

                //Console.Write("{0}", start);
                firstName = String.Format("{0}", start);
                return firstName;
            }                
        }
        return firstName;
    }
```

**UnitTest:**

```
[TestCase("Alex", "AAlAleAlex")]
    public void FunnyName(string firstName, string expected)
    {
        var actual = warmups.FunnyName(firstName);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: "_but it only returns the first letter for some reason_" No, not for some reason. For exactly this reason: `firstName = String.Format("{0}", start); return firstName;`. `start` is a `char` (a character). So, obviously you generate a string here that consists of just one character and assign it to the `firstName` variable as well as immediately returning it. It's all there in your code, you just need to look at it... ;-)

Comment: By the way, by adding a `return` inside the `for` loop it will only execute up to **one** iteration of the loop before exiting

Answer (score 3):

A little hard to follow your question, but I think you want this maybe??

```
public string FunnyName(string firstName)
{
    var s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < firstName.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            s.Append(firstName[j]);

    return s.ToString();
}
```